# A light PDF viewer inside a webpage

Tags: pdf, integration

which free PDF viewers are available to directly show a PDF file inside a webpage?

I don't want to use Adobe Reader integration because I don't like it. I tried with Google Docs Viewer and it works fine but doesn't resize as I resize the page..

I would like to know if something quite light that can also be easily resized according to the page exists.. any suggestions?

Comment: If PDF documents are created by your web application maybe you can try to export them to HTML on the server and avoid completely PDF. JasperReports has such a feature as well as many other reporting tools.

Comment: They are graphical since it's a sort of catalogue splitted in many sections.. I just need a fancy way to integrate them inside the webpage. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this example it seems that google viewer resize as i resize the page [URLTOFILE](http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=URLTOFILE).
It's beeing discussed at this [support forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/thread?tid=343d189e740fb7d0&hl=en). "To embed:
Put http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=URLTOFILE&embedded=true into an `<IFRAME>`". Here is another [example](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html) for google viewer.

Comment: I tried exactly that the latter link (googlesystem.blogspot.com) but it seemed not to resize.. I also tried removing style width and height!

Comment: Managed to make it work by tweaking CSS attributes.. thanks for making me trying again :)